# How to create a matrix in simple correspondence analysis?

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to create a matrix in order to apply a simple correspondence analysis on it; I have 2 categorical variables: `exp` and `conexinternet` with 3 levels each.

```
obs  conexinternet exp
 1             1   2
 2             1   1
 3             2   2
 4             1   1
 5             1   1
 6             2   1
 7             1   2
 8             1   2
 9             1   2
10             2   1
11             1   1
12             2   1
13             2   2
14             2   1
15             1   1
16             2   2
17             1   1
18             2   2
19             2   2
20             2   2
21             2   2
22             1   1
23             2   3
24             1   1
25             2   1
26             2   1
27             1   1
28             2   2
29             2   1
30             1   2
31             1   2
32             2   3
33             2   1
34             2   1
35             2   1
36             3   2
37             2   1
38             3   2
39             2   3
40             2   3
41             2   2
42             2   3
43             2   2
44             2   2
45             2   1
46             2   2
47             2   3
48             1   3
49             2   3
50             3   2
51             2   2
52             2   2
53             2   1
54             1   2
55             1   1
56             2   3
57             3   2
58             3   1
59             3   1
60             1   2
61             2   3
62             2   2
63             3   1
64             3   2
65             3   2
66             1   2
67             3   2
68             3   2
69             3   3
70             2   1
71             3   3
72             3   2
73             3   2
74             3   2
75             3   1
76             3   2
77             3   1
```

I want to make a vector to categorize the observations as `11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23, 31, 32, 33`, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
d <- read.table(text="obs  conexinternet exp
 1             1   2
...
77             3   1", header=T)

(tab <- xtabs(~conexinternet+exp, d))
#              exp
# conexinternet  1  2  3
#             1 10  9  1
#             2 14 15  9
#             3  5 12  2
```